# SSH config: default password, except as specified

Tags: linux, ssh

When I type `ssh <server>` I want the default behavior to be a password prompt, except for hosts explicitly defined in my `.ssh/config` file for which I have created public/private key pairs.

My config file currently looks like so:

```
Host *
    PubkeyAuthentication no

Host <private-server>
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile <private-server>_key
```

If I comment out the two `Host *` lines, then it uses my private key to connect to `<private-server>`. With the two `Host *` lines uncommented, however, it requests a password despite the `PubkeyAuthentication yes` line.

How do I fix this?

Comment: My answer solves your original problem. If a separate answer appears that solves the bonus, which one will you accept? **You have two separate problems, so ask two separate questions.**

Comment: I did a rollback to keep the site tidy. Nothing personal. You will find your "bonus" [under this link](https://superuser.com/revisions/1241951/2). Use it to [ask another question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), really.

Comment: I plan on accepting the answer which solves the first problem, I just realized  my other issue was also related to an understanding of the ssh config file so I included it (coincidentally simultaneously as your answer). If the bonus points got no response I would have simply left it alone and maybe asked another day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

Your `Host *` section is most general. It should be at the very end.

Comment: Just gave this a try and it fixed my issue. I updated the issue just 60 seconds ago with a "bonus points" section, any insight on that as well?