# use ssh config defaults without hostname

Tags: ssh

Is it somehow possible to use a default ssh config without a hostname? of course I know how to use `~/.ssh/config`, but I want to do something like:

```
Host myservers
  User root
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/specialkey
```

- `ssh myservers server1.de`
- `ssh myservers server2.de`

but that wont work, so I cannot use a ssh config and define the server/hostname afterwards. That means for now I always have to do `ssh -i ~/.ssh/specialkey -O IdentitiesOnly=yes root@server1.de` or what other possibilities would I have here to use?

Comment: What's wrong with `Host server1.de server2.de`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski its about 100-200 servers ...

Comment: `Host server*.de`?

Comment: I still dont understand how that should work, maybe you can post it more verbose as an answer?

Comment: My answer now includes the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the snippet so it applies to the hosts in question:

```
Host server1.de server2.de
  User root
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/specialkey
```

Then you just `ssh server1.de` or `ssh server2.de`.

You can add more entries to the `Host` line. If the settings should apply to a group of servers with a common naming scheme, consider using wildcards. E.g. `Host server*.de`.

Make sure you put the snippet early enough in your config (because [the first obtained value for each parameter is used](https://superuser.com/a/1241953/432690)). Definitely before `Host *`.

---

If you want to use some special config on demand, put the config in another file and use `ssh -F`.

> `-F configfile`
> Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file. If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) will be ignored. The default for the per-user configuration file is `~/.ssh/config`. […]

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#F))</sup>

Example:

```
ssh -F ~/.ssh/myservers server1.de
```

Notes:

- The config may contain `Host *` as the only section, so it will work for any server you want.
- You can create two or more configs, each in a separate file, and pick whichever you want when you connect.
- An alias

  ```
  alias ssh-myservers='ssh -F ~/.ssh/myservers'
  ```

  will allow you to connect almost as you wanted: `ssh-myservers server1.de`.
- A wrapper script or a shell function can allow you to connect exactly as you wanted. Example function:

  ```
  ssh() {
     configfile=~/".ssh/$1"
     if [ -f "$configfile" ]; then
        shift; command ssh -F "$configfile" "$@"
     else
        command ssh "$@"
     fi }
  ```

  To connect with `ssh myservers server1.de` you need the config to be in `~/.ssh/myservers`.