# ssh config vs command line for ProxyJump options

Tags: ssh

I have the following network
Laptop --> aaaa@X1.Y1.Z1.A1  ----> aaaa@X2.Y2.Z2.A2 ----> xxxx@X3.Y3.Z3.A3

I have setup passwordless login and the following command works (i.e.) there are 2 jump servers and then the final host

```
ssh -v -X -A -J aaaa@X1.Y1.Z1.A1,aaaa@X2.Y2.Z2.A2 xxxx@X3.Y3.Z3.A3 -L P1:X3.Y3.Z3.A3:P1
```

I am trying to put the above in a config and this is the config file

```
Host h3
        Hostname X3.Y3.Z3.A3
        User xxxx
        ProxyJump h2

Host h2
        Hostname X2.Y2.Z2.A2
        User aaaa
        ProxyJump h1

Host h1
        Hostname X1.Y1.Z1.A1
        User aaaa
```

I try `ssh -v -A -X h3` and I get a connection closed error .

Can somebody help me with the correct config file?

Comment: Is it the whole config file? See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1241953/432690). Maybe some earlier part of the config interferes.

Comment: Yes this is the whole config file